# What Does 'new' Do In C#?

Tags: c#

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
class Car()
{
    int speed = 50;
}
```

Now imagine in some other file, you do

```
Car truck;
```

How is that different from

```
Car truck = new car();
```

I've been using C# for a little over a year, but still don't get this. It's been an on and off type of thing.

Comment: `new` causes a new instance of the class of type `car` to be instantiated. Your code also assigns that instance to the variable called `truck`.

Comment: `Car truck;` is just a declaration. `Car truck = new car()` declares and initialises `truck` to point to a `car` instance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seriously, google prior to asking on SO. https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/fa0ab757.aspx

Comment: Is there somewhere in the SO rules that explain how this is off-topic? I agree it's a simple question, but we all started somewhere.

Comment: And my answer gets nucked by put on hold... While it is simple it is certainly something that can be answered.

Comment: Down-votes; closed as _"does not appear to be about programming"_.  How is this any different to say _[Can somebody please explain async / await?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/can-somebody-please-explain-async-await)_ bearing in mind _[Are “beginner questions” allowed on Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152066/are-beginner-questions-allowed-on-stackoverflow)_

Answer (score 1):

`Car truck;` doesn't *do* anything. All you're saying with that line of code is that you may or may not eventually have an object of type `Car`, and you'll want to refer to it as `truck`.

`Car truck = new Car();` declares that you've want to refer to a `Car` with the name `truck` (just like before), but then you *also* give that name to an actual `Car` object that you are instantiating in place.

To continue the car analogy with a (somewhat flawed) concept: `Car truck;` is a parking spot, `Car truck = new Car();` is a parking spot you just built a new car in.

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I see no other posts here. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first say that whether it is a `class` or `struct` matters heavily in how this all works out, but for now I will ignore `struct` to simplify things:

> Now imagine in some other file, you do
>   `Car truck;`

This creates a variable (or field in some cases) that could contain a `Car` instance, however it does not create such an instance. Note that if it is actually a field (because it is in a `class` definition and not in a method) then it will get the default value `null`. If it is a local variable then attempting to access it is a compiler error.

This isn't an instance of `Car` and attempting to treat it as such will cause an error to occur unless it is a field and you are calling a method that will accept a null.

> How is that different from
>   `Car truck = new car();`

By putting the `= new Car();` before the `;` you are telling the language to give you an instance using the default constructor (that is a term for the `()` constructor). This causes a new instance of the class to be created and the constructor you provided to be called to initialize that new instance.

Note that in this case you have a valid `Car` that will work as you expect, compared to the previous one where you did not have one at all.

In short if you want a place to hold a `Car` use the first definition, if you actually want a car, use the second.

---

Now I am going to expand on `struct`, it is important to keep in mind but they aren't nearly as common as classes so you can focus on the above.

> Now imagine in some other file, you do
>   `StructCar truck;`
>   How is that different from
>   `StructCar truck = new StructCar();`

These are now identical, they both create a variable or field and calls the default constructor for the `StructCar`. This will in turn set each field to its default value (calling the default constructor on any `struct` and setting any `class` to `null`). This is a perfectly valid `StructCar` but be careful, because every time you give it to someone (by saying calling a method and passing it as an argument) they will get a copy, not the original. Also note that in the definition of `StructCar` you cannot define a default constructor, it will also do what I am describing here.