# Why is it not necessary to return a Task when the signature is public async Task MethodName?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have some code that is working fine but I don't understand why. My method performs some SQL operations using the ExecuteReaderAsync, ExecuteNonQueryAsync, and WriteToServerAsync. WriterToServerAsync is the last one I call.

I originally wrote the method with the signature public async void Run() but the Hangfire job runner I am using won't accept async unless it returns a Task. I changed the signature to async Task Run() and then tried to figure out how to return a Task from the method.

I thought that I could just return the same task that was being returned from WriteToServerAsync but this would not compile. I ended deleting the return statement altogether. The compiler does not complain and the method works fine.

```
public async Task Run()
{
    // Start querying the source first as it is the slowest operation...
    var sqlSourceConnection = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString);

    // The query is kind of slow so it needs more than the default 30 second timeout...
    var sqlSourceCommand = new SqlCommand(SourceDataSql, sqlSourceConnection) { CommandTimeout = 180 };

    sqlSourceConnection.Open();

    // Query the records from the source...
    var querySourceDataTask = sqlSourceCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    // Delete existing records from target to make way for the new set...
    var sqlTargetConnection = new SqlConnection(targetConnectionString);

    sqlTargetConnection.Open();
    var sqlTargetTransaction = sqlTargetConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

    var deleteRowsTask = sqlDeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

    // Wait for the delete and query tasks to finish before attempting the bulk copy...
    await Task.WhenAll(deleteRowsTask, querySourceDataTask);

    await sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync(querySourceDataTask.Result);
}
```

Why does this compile and work without a return statement for the Task?

Comment: This is the basics of [how async/await works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/can-somebody-please-explain-async-await).

Comment: This guy has very good blog, where you can find a lot of interesting stuff about async/await. And more:) http://blog.stephencleary.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does this compile and work without a return statement for the Task?

Because the return type Task is the equivalent of void (a method that doesn't return any value) for an *asynchronous* method that can be awaited.

Please refer to the following links for more information about the async/await keywords in C#.

**Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

**Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#):** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: Perfect. Those articles are great resource to get me up to speed on async.