# How can an "async" task return an integer and not a public one?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, type-conversion

I just had following piece of code, which did not compile:

```
public Task<int> Handle
{
    var result = <do_something_returning_an_int>();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

This gives compiler error `cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Threading.Thread.Task'.

When I change this into:

```
async Task<int> Handle
{
    var result = <do_something_returning_an_int>();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

... no compiler error.

I know that `async` means that the task does not need to wait for the answer to arrive, but what does this have to do with typecasting?

Comment: Is the method using an `await` anywhere?  If the method isn't `async` then it won't automatically produce a `Task<>`, the code would need to return that type explicitly.  And an `int` is not a `Task<int>`.  (The difference between those types has exactly nothing to do with the `public` access modifier.)

Comment: I would suggest to make both methods `public`, to eliminate any confusion regarding this difference.

Comment: `async` actually means: this method has something that can be `await`ed. Otherwise there's no need to use `async`.

Comment: This is a part of the C# Language Specification. Read it, or read [Async return types (C#) § `Task<TResult>` return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#tasktresult-return-type).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: your comment seems to be the closest to the solution. Can you put it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(By request, promoted from a comment.)

This is by design of the `async` logic in the [C# Language Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/). See the section [Async Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#1415-async-functions).

You can also read the programming guide, [Async return types (C#) § Task<TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#tasktresult-return-type).

The point is that a method *without* the `async` keyword, like

```
public Task<int> HandleAsync()
{
    ...
    Task<int> result = ...;
    ...
    return result;
}
```

must return what it says it returns, just as with all other types. In this case, you could create a `Task<>` that can be awaited, in your own manual way, like:

```
Task<int> result = Task.Run(GetLastDigitOfSmallestTwinPrimeWithMoreThan1000000Digits);
```

The caller can `await` the task you return, even if your method is written like above.

But if you use the `async` keyword, and if your return type is, say, `Task<int>`, then you must return a plain `int`, and **the C# compiler will write the needed logic** for you.

Usually, you would use `await` somewhere in the body (otherwise, why `async`). So something like:

```
public async Task<int> HandleAsync()
{
    ...
    int result = await GetLastDigitOfSmallestTwinPrimeWithMoreThan1000000DigitsAsync();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Related question here: [Why is it not necessary to return a Task when the signature is public async Task MethodName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334231/)

Comment: Another related thread: [async await return Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191512/).

Answer (score 5):

If you're not awaiting anything in your asynchronous method you omit the `async` keyword and return a `Task` instead of the result directly.

```
public Task<int> Handle
{
    var result = <do_something_returning_an_int>();
    ...
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

As far as I can tell, doing that only makes sense if other code strictly expects a `Task` from your method.

This has of course nothing to do with access modifiers, you can combine `async` with `public` or any other access modifier.

I'd also recommend taking a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async)

Answer (score 1):

try using task result and then iterate the results

```
Task<int> Handle
{
    return Task.Run(()=>
    {
       var result = <do_something_returning_an_int>();
       ...
       return result;
    }
}

List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
tasks.Add(Handle);
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
for(int ctr = 0; ctr < tasks.Count; ctr++) {
                if (tasks[ctr].Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
                    output.WriteLine(" Task fault occurred");
                else
                {
                    output.WriteLine("test sent {0}",
                                      tasks[ctr].Result);
                    Assert.True(true);
                }
            }
```

or

```
Task<int> Handle
{
   return Task.FromResult(do_something_returning_an_int);
}
```