# Task<byte[]> method warns about implicit cast without async

Tags: c#, task

I have created a method to gather entropy for my application.
I've put this in a Task to provide an asynchronous operation for the caller.
I want to avoid a forever loop when collecting entropy from the sensors so I used a timeout which defaults to using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes()` method.

```
public Task<byte[]> GetEntropy1(int length)
{
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider entropyGen = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] entropyBuffer = new byte[2048];

    try
    {
        semaphore.Wait();

        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            /* gather entropy from sensors */
        });

        if (!t.Wait(5000))
        {
            entropyGen.GetBytes(entropyBuffer);
        }
        return entropyBuffer;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return entropyBuffer;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

But I don't understand why when I return the byte array, I get a warning about implicit cast.
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'**

If I use an `async` in the function definition, then that warning goes away.

Comment: Because when you await, you get the result of the task (byte[]) and without it, you get the task itself. It's how it works

Comment: Does "gather entropy from sensors" return a Task? If so, then await it instead of using Task.Run. As it stands, there is nothing asynchronous about your method, so no point in using tasks.

Comment: The entropy gathering may involve a `while..loop` (still looking into it). I wanted to timeout to avoid it not exiting for whatever reason.

Comment: @Petaflop So by having the `async` in the function signature, but without using `await()` in my method, this allows me to return the result rather than the Task object?

Comment: @just_another_engineer `async` keyword does nothing by itself. This answer and Stephen's link to his blog may help you to understand how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14178317/6009117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `async` involves the compiler re-writing your method and *one of the things it does* is to wrap return values in a `Task`. Without it, no re-writing occurs, and as the error says, a `byte[]` *isn't* a `Task<byte[]>`.

You could write [`Task.FromResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.7.2) at each of your `return` points<sup>1</sup> to do your own manual wrapping.

---

<sup>1</sup>Although once you remove the nasty `catch` clause that's just going to *hide* errors from you later, you'll only have one anyway.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thank you.