# Why returning Task.CompletedTask failed to compile in an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm using VS2019 and dotnetcore 3.1 for a simple console application, I've this code piece:

```
public static async Task F()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Task.CompletedTask; // error
}
```

It doesn't compile. I just with to create a method that is (1) async, and (2) returns a Task. Why this return statement doesn't compile? How to fix it to fulfill my requirement of (1) and (2)?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should only use `Task.CompletedTask` when you need to return a task and you're not using async/await.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method could functionally be condensed down to this.

```
public static Task F() 
{ 
  return Task.Delay(1000); 
}
```

Returning an `Task.CompletedTask` instance is only useful if these apply:

- you do not want to use `async/await`
- your method returns a Task (effectively `void` if you were to make it not asynchronous)
- your code has logic where a task might not be returned

Example:

```
public static Task F() 
{ 
  if (someConditionToShortCircutTheMethod) 
      return Task.CompletedTask;

  // rest of logic
  return Task.Delay(1000); 
}
```

As soon as you make your method `async` then the fact that a Task is actually being returned is abstracted. This can make the code easier to work with especially if there are multiple points where the code waits for I/O operations to complete.

```
public static async Task F() 
{ 
  if (someConditionToShortCircutTheMethod) 
      return;

  // rest of logic
  await Task.Delay(1000); 
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  // no return necessary, async Task has a similar flow as return type void
}
```

I also recommend reviewing these previous questions:

- [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293/1260204)
- [Understanding async / await in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14177891/1260204)

Answer (score 5):

`await Task.Delay(1000);` method already creates and returns a `Task`, so you could write

```cs
public static async Task F()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Or use `await` with `Task.CompletedTask;`

```cs
public static async Task F()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Otherwise you should update return type to `Task<Task>`, which doesn't make a lot of sense

```cs
public static async Task<Task> F()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't compile. I just with to create a method that is (1) async, and (2) returns a Task. Why this return statement doesn't compile? How to fix it to fulfill my requirement of (1) and (2)?

[The `async` keyword will instruct the compiler to create a state machine, and it is the job of that state machine to create the `Task` returned from this method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). So you don't need to return a `Task` if you're using `async`:

```
public static async Task F()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return;
}
```

or equivalently:

```
public static async Task F()
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Greate explaination for async state machine and Task return.