# Is Fire & Forget (HTTP call) possible without using a separate thread?

Tags: java

We are required to call an HTTP endpoint but our main process is restricted to be single-threaded (we are running multiple instances of the same process and we don't have enough resource on the machine).

Is it possible to do a fire and forget to do it?
Options I always see (which I understand and appreciate) are `ExecutorService`, `@Async` or other approaches that essentially creates a new thread (or uses an existing one).

Is this doable?

Comment: No. A thread can do only one thing at a time.

Comment: Does timing-out out of the HTTP request early (like after 5 seconds) even help here?

Comment: you could use nonblocking http clients, including a built-in in java `HttpClient`, however they would use auxiliary thread under the hood

Comment: @Jorn That's [only partially accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/understanding-async-await-in-c-sharp). While threads are technically only doing one thing at a time, asynchronous programming allows threads to do other tasks while they're waiting for slow external processes (such as network calls).

Comment: @EJoshuaS I don't see how that's relevant to the question. You either block your main thread or you use a second thread.

Comment: @Jorn That's not true at all. Plenty of languages offer non-blocking I/O and network calls, which typically don't require the creation of additional threads. Please see the article I link to for an explanation of why C#'s async calls don't require additional threads. Java admittedly doesn't appear to have particularly great support for this, but that's not an accurate statement in the general case.

Comment: *our main process is restricted to be single-threaded* Has anyone involved in coming up with that restriction ever counted the number of threads any instance of `java` has?  Adding one more to that isn't going to change much.

Comment: Do you need GET or POST?

Comment: @gdomo, we are POSTing some data but we don't care about the results.

Comment: @EJoshuaS If you are talking about Project Loom's Virtual Threads... I still say that's out of scope for this question. Don't make thing more difficult than they need to be. Even if you are right about what *can* be done, it doesn't help OP. As for non-blocking IO... there's always *something* that waits for it to complete. Whether that's a full thread, virtual thread, coroutine or something else doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an answer you could open connection and synchronously send your data without waiting for response. For example, with basic built-in java URLConnection:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Header-name", "header value");
try (OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream()) {
    os.write("any payload".getBytes());
    os.flush();
}
try (InputStream ignored = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
}
urlConnection.disconnect();
```

It wouldn't wait for response, however sending the data could also take a while. More information on URLConnection [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).
Also, be cautious, it's up to the server how it would handle premature connection close, which would happen if you don't wait for the answer.