Task.WaitAll using Task.Run with async/await vs without
I am trying to understand how the code below would behave differently if the functions used in Task.Run were not async/await when calling GetAllData.
Am I correct that GetAllData will behave the same regardless of what is used with Task.Run?  Meaning that it will block until all of the tasks are completed?  If that is true, how does the flow change when removing the async/await from Task.Run, assuming GetData1/GetData2 are long running CPU-bound methods?
public Task GetAllData()
{
    Task.WaitAll(
        Task.Run(async () => await SomeFunction(() => GetData1)),
        Task.Run(async () => await SomeFunction(() => GetData2))

        //versus
        //Task.Run(() => SomeFunction(() => GetData1)),
        //Task.Run(() => SomeFunction(() => GetData2))
    );
    Debug.Writeline("All tasks completed");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

async Task SomeFunction(Action action)
{
    //do some work.
    await action.TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
}

async Task TimeoutAfter(this Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var task = Task.Run(action);
    if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task)
    {
        await task;
    }
    else
    {
        //timeout logic
    }
}


You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177891/understanding-async-await-in-c-sharp

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html TL;DR The async & await are superfluous in your example. The commented out version will behave the same, and with a negligible performance benefit.

Also worth reading: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Why return a Task when the method blocks? You could have used await Task.WhenAll intead, or return Task.WhenAll. The nested Task.Run calls don't help either.
